# ConvertCents.java:31: error: variable centsLeft might not have been initialized

Tags: java

i found this problem when i try to modify the code

```
ConvertCents.java:31: error: variable centsLeft might not have been initialized
      numQuarters = centsLeft/QUARTERS;
                    ^
1 error
```

```java
    import java.util.Scanner;

    public class ConvertCents {
     
       final static int QUARTERS = 25;             
       final static int DIMES = 10;                
       final static int NICKELS = 5;               

       public static void main (String[] args) {
          int cents;                               
              int numQuarters, numDimes, numNickels;                      
              int centsLeft;
                                   
          System.out.println("Cents to Coins Program");
          System.out.println("----------------------");

          Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
          System.out.println("Enter total number of cents (positive integer): ");
          cents = keyboard.nextInt();
          System.out.println();

          
          numQuarters = centsLeft/QUARTERS;
          centsLeft = centsLeft % QUARTERS;
          numDimes = centsLeft/DIMES;
          centsLeft = centsLeft % DIMES;
          numNickels = centsLeft/NICKELS;
          centsLeft = centsLeft % NICKELS;

          // display resulting number of coins
          System.out.print("For your total cents of  " + cents);
          System.out.println("  you have:");
          System.out.println("#quarters = " + numQuarters);
          System.out.println("#dimes = " + numDimes);
          System.out.println("#nickels = " + numNickels);
          System.out.println("#pennies = " + centsLeft);
          System.out.println();
       }
    }
```

Comment: Well, you reference `centsLeft` in that line, but you don't initialize it until the next line.  You can't reference a value that doesn't exist yet.

Comment: could you explain more?

Comment: So in your line `numQuarters = centsLeft / QUARTERS;`, you are assigning `numQuarters` to the value of `centsLeft` divided by the value of `QUARTERS`.  The value of `QUARTERS` is `25`, you specified that at the top of your class file.  But what is the value of `centsLeft`?  You haven't specified that, so the compiler doesn't know what to do.